# Запись структуры в бинарный файл

Tags: c++, visual-c++

### Заголовок

Написал структуру. Хочу ее поместить в бинарный файл. Все получилось. Но последний пункт структуры не вводится (char znak[8]). Компилятор в тупую его пропускает. раз через раз. То пропускает, то выбивает программу. Вот текст. Помогите советом

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
struct vvod
{

    char fio[24];
    int srok;
    char tip_avto[8];
    char tiv_garaga[13];
    int nomer;
    char znak[8];
};

int main()
{

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    const char * kat_avto_l = "Легковая";
    const char * kat_avto_g = "Грузовая";
    const char * kat_garaga_m = "Металлический";
    const char * kat_garaga_k = "Кирпичный";
    FILE * kar;
    vvod mas[6];
    int b, z, z_v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        kar = fopen("kar.bin", "wb");
        cout << "ФИО арендатора\nВаш выбор:";
        gets_s(mas[i].fio);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Срок аренды гаража:\nВаш выбор:";
        cin >> mas[i].srok;
        system("cls");
        cout << "Тип авто:\n1.Легковая.\n2.Грузовая.\nВаш выбор:";
        cin >> b;
        switch (b)
        {
        case 1:
            strcpy(mas[i].tip_avto, kat_avto_l);
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(mas[i].tip_avto, kat_avto_g);
            break;
        }
        system("cls");
        cout << "Тип гаража:\n1.Металлический.\n2.Кирпичный.\nВаш выбор:";
        cin >> z;
        switch (z)
        {
        case 1:
            strcpy(mas[i].tiv_garaga, kat_garaga_m);
            z_v = mas[i].srok * 2500;
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(mas[i].tiv_garaga, kat_garaga_k);
            z_v = mas[i].srok * 5000;
            break;
        }   
        system("cls");
        cout << "Место гаража (1-99):\nВаш выбор:";
        cin >> mas[i].nomer;
        system("cls");
        getchar();
        cout << "Регистрационный автомобильный знак:\nВаш выбор:";
        gets_s(mas[i].znak);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Анкета заполненна:)"; 
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы вводите в `znak`, похоже, строку из 8 или более символов...

Comment: Я заменил его на 'string znak;' и все заработало:)

Comment: Это не противоречит моей версии :)